# Java 7 Underscore Numeric literals

Tags: java, java-7

Why Java 7 include feature of underscore numeric literals why not comma numeric literals?

Comment: Note: comma is not a universal standard. There are countries where the number `1000.45` would be represented as `1,000.45`, and countries where it is represented as `1.000,45`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "," operator already has meaning, so existing code would change meaning:

```
// Is this 3 values or 2?
int[] values = { 123,456, 789 };
```